# Tomar ScreenShot y convertirlo a jpg

Tags: java, android, screenshot

Como tomar un ScreenShot en un area determinada convertirlo a jpg, almacenarlo en un archivo dentro de mi memoria y luego poder exportarlo. Necesito tomar captura solo de lo que se encuentra dentro de mi @+id/linearLayout16

Investigue un poco y me encontré con esto. por lo que se ve funciona, pero no puedo modificarlo a mi gusto. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228239/android-capture-screenshot-programmatically-without-title-bar

a continuancion dejo mi xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constrain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#3C5C97"
        android:text="@string/espacio"
        android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView36"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF867D"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNumero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewApellido"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numA9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numB9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC1"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC3"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC4"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC6"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC7"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC8"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_numC9"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmar_number_custom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3C5C97"
            android:text="@string/espacio"
            android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#3C5C97"
        android:text="@string/espacio"
        android:textColor="#3C5C97" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout15"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_cancelar"
        android:onClick="Salir" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_editar"
        android:onClick="Editar" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_boton_borrar"
        android:onClick="Borrar_dialog" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView43"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cancelar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView42"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/editar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView41"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/borrar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Actualizo con código el cual tome de ejemplo. Este código no esta en nada relacionado al xml anterior. este código es el que saque de ejemplo y quiero modificar para el xml anteriormente visto.(aclaro que el código funciona pero cuando intento llevarlo a mi aplicación ya no lo hace)

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {

        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".png";

        View u = findViewById(R.id.tabScroll);
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.tabScroll);
        z.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
        u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
        u.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
        u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que bonito pero, ¿Y el código de la actividad?

Comment: Importa el código de mi actividad para lo que necesito hacer? solo quiero tener una imagen jpg. Es mucho código, se haría muy larga mi pregunta @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Cual es el código que no funciona para tomar el Screenshot?

Comment: ¿Y es que como se supone que sepamos dónde está el error o cuál es el problema sino vemos el código? @FranSchiavone

Comment: No tenia código hasta el momento. solo el del ejemplo que tome como referencia, ahí actualice con dicho código. Saludos.